# Is it possible to translate Oracle Forms6 application to Windows Forms (.net)?

Tags: .net, winforms, oracleforms

Is there any tool that would help to move/translate appliaction written in Oracle Forms 6 to .Net Windows Forms ?

Maybe not th whole application at once, but maybe modules/forms(screens) to windows forms.

I know that languages are different (pl/sql vs .net), but maybe that tool could make some templates and programmer would be responsible to translate business logic from pl/sql to .net language (c# for example).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Forms2Net](http://forms2net.atxsoftware.com/site/welcome.do). Our company evaluated it before deciding on a different direction, but it looked pretty slick. A bit pricey, but most of the conversion tools out there are. It had many of the features you're looking for. It is able to convert much of the PL/SQL straight over, and what it can't it reports to you.

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 17 in the TechNet Interoperability and Migration library is devoted to this topic.  Money quote:

> "The basic approach is feasible for
>   the following two reasons:
>
> 1. Oracle Forms and Visual Basic user interfaces share many common elements.
> 2. The Oracle Forms Designer is capable to generate [sic] Visual Basic
>      code."

[Find out more](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463141.aspx).

Also, it might be worth contracting Microsoft Pre-Sales.  I'm sure they will be happy, even gleeful, to assist you in your endeavours.

---

Hmm, I notice I am answering your question in the title (is it possible?  yes it is) rather than the question in the body which is more about tools to support the process.  I think Forms2Net is the only game in town.

As a general observation, I have seen tools which do the same process for Java.  They turn to produce bad, convoluted code.  Because translating from the idioms of one language to another is *hard*.  I an not casting aspersions at Forms2Net, I have never looked at it, but I think you should really consider the benefits of manual migration - better implementation, developer familiarity with code base.  Of course, the scope of those benefits depends on your particular situation.